# How to "Sin-1 (x)" to degrees in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to reproduce the following formula in excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eTW7.png)

Then I entered the following in excel

`=0.5 * SIN( ((450*(10^3))/(300*500))/(0.153*(250*(1-(25/250)))))^-1`

But it produces `0.6..` as the answer, but the answer should be 30.3 degrees.

Where have I done wrong? What's the correct method to use `negative sine` function in excel?

Comment: Did you mean ASIN() as in the function to turn a sin to a number?

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't the `sin^-1` from your picture denoting the inverse function (`asin`) of `sin`. Ie `sin^-1(sin(x)) == x` whereas `y^(-z)` in excel is the equivalent of `1/y^z`

Comment: @SolarMike Yes :)

Comment: @derpirscher yes, I was going towards the wrong direction. thanks all of you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula you entered in Excel is incorrect. The inverse sine function in Excel is represented by the ASIN function, not by using the negative power operator ^-1. The correct formula would be: =ASIN(0.5) * (180/PI()) This will give you the correct answer of 30.3 degrees in radians, which you can then convert to degrees by multiplying by 180/PI().

Comment: Yes, I was completely going towards the wrong direction. You're a lifesaver.